# How to calculate commissions based on the threshold in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a threshold limit like below,

```
5000 - 10000 is 20%
10000 - 20000 is 25%
20000 - above is 35%
```

if my input is 40000 then the output should be ( 20% of 10000) + (25% of 20000) + (35% of 10000) .

Could someone help, please?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you stuck?

Comment: use `if` to to this, try at your end first and let us know if you stuck..

Comment: So there is no commission on sales less than 5k?

Comment: Did you mean to tag [excel-vba] for this thread? You can do this with an Excel formula.

Comment: To get started with if just do the 5000 to 10000 case and make it returns zero for less than 5k, the commission times sales -5000 for between 5000 and 10000 and the commission times (10000-5000) for greater than 10k. Once you have that, you should be able to create two similar formulas and add all three.

Answer (score 0):

assuming your data is layed out as shown below

[image]

in cell F1 you can place the value you want to calculate your commission on.

in cell G1 place the following formula which should calculate the commission:

```
=IF(F1<$A$1,0,IF(F1<$A$2,$D$1*F1,IF(F1<$A$3,$A$2*$D$1+(F1-$A$2)*$D$2,$A$2*$D$1+($A$3-$A$2)*$D$2+(F1-$A$3)*$D$3)))
```